# Y axis does not disappear after setting extremes

Tags: highcharts

I cannot remove Y axis after I do : `chart.yAxis[i].setExtremes(0, 100);`. I need to be able to set max and min values for the axis dynamically, based on the index of yAxis - in this case I pass 1. All the other axis disappear fine because this line of code doesn't affect them. What's going on ? Fiddle ( click on Rainfall in the legend): http://jsfiddle.net/ytxetjpL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis is hidden when the scale is not set (via min/max or setExtremes). More information here on [github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/705).

This addition should solve the issue.

```
Highcharts.Axis.prototype.hasData = function() {
  return this.hasVisibleSeries;
};
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ytxetjpL/1/